# Storing version change information in a specialized Assembly Attribute

Tags: c#

After a conversation with a colleague about storing version change log type information in a specialized assembly attribute, I thought I'd ask the wider community for their thoughts.

I.e, each assembly has a version field, it's not a large step to consider rudimentary version change information stuffed into a specialized attribute in the assembly.

Please note this would be for in-house applications, not public.

From the conversation:

**Pros might be**

- Change information is stored in the assembly with a version number
- Change information can be enumerated from an assembly for various reasons
- Version and change information is in the one place
- Change logs are usually associated with an assembly

However I can't really come up with good fundamental arguments why this would be a bad idea.

**Cons might be**

- won't look good in the assembly extended property information?
- bloat the assembly?
- Attack vector?

Example:

```
[assembly: AssemblyChangeInformation(
    {1.0.0.1, "Added Something",
              "Done Something else"
              ...}),
    {1.0.0.2, "Some bug fix"},
    {1.0.0.3, "blah ..."})]
```

Please be aware I'm not for or against this idea.

I'm just wondering what the pros and more specifically the cons are, so I can go back to the powers-that-be with an enlightened argument for or against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information should be stored in a revision control software like SVN, as long as you write log into SVN when you commit code changes and remember to increment the version number at each build you can easily associate the right assembly with the change history, there is no need to store the information in "one place".

If you store this information in attributes, you need to develop a decent viewer - or at least some helper code - to view the change logs. Can't beat SVN, right?

Comment: Yeah good point, i guess the only advantage in the assembly in this respect would be version information displayable in the app, however i fully agree with you about svn being the source of truth... oh and every answer wins a prize